# Prestashop - importing a csv file fails with no error

Tags: csv, import, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a problem with Prestashop's CSV importing tool and I couldn't find the same issue anywhere on the forum.
When I try to import a csv file, it shows as if it was successful but no products are added to my shop. 
First I thought my csv file was corrupted, but I made another one from scratch, inline with Prestashop's recommendations for csv files, but I still can not import it.
There are no errors displayed and this thing is driving me nuts.
The Prestashop version I am using is the download version, 1.6.1.3.

Any ideas for why is this happening?

I also attached my demo csv file. [demoFile screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEKsE.jpg)

Comment: Do you have any error in your server log files ?

Comment: Not from what I can see. I also tried to import the same file on a test account that i made with Prestashop Cloud, same version - 1.6.1.3 and the test went well, had the same behavior (no errors on the page) and the products were successfully added to the shop. The only difference on the test account was that it took a little longer after I clicked the import button, until I got redirected on back to the initial page. So clearly must be some configuration issues with the download version that I can't figure it out.

Comment: Is your Prestashop in Demo Mode ? you can check in config/defines.inc.php if _PS_MODE_DEMO_ is false.

Comment: If you're not in Demo Mode you'll have to debug /controllers/admin/adminImportController.php method postProcess and var_dump your csv file to see what is wrong.

Comment: I found the file, but unfortunately I have limited knowledge of php so I wasn't able to sort it out yet. Could you please provide me a sample or a snippet of how the code in this file should look so I can then check and make the needed adjustments? Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://imgur.com/Lnmb4c3 - this is how postProcess function looks like for me, any ideea what might be the issue?

Comment: A lot of not displayed errors occurs when you develop a module in prestashop 1.6.x, the log of error of your server is necesary here. You must to erase the server logs and repeat the process to record the error and do easier the search. An aplication for read server logs is very useful.